# systemd-shutdown[1]: Waiting for process: python

Tags: python

When I switch off my laptop (Ubuntu 20.04) I get the message

```
systemd-shutdown[1]: Waiting for process: python
```

I used to have the same thing for **containerd-shim** and I've found online a workaround to force shutting down all the docker stuff, a .service file placed under */etc/systemd/system*.

Can anyone help me achieving the same with Python?

I know I can reduce the **DefaultTimeoutStopSec** in the *system.conf* file but I'd like to have all the Python jobs off instead.